# different log-rank test : ggsurvplot and proc lifetest

Tags: r, sas, survival-analysis

When I am using ggsurvplot on R, I get a different log-rank test than a PROC LIFETEST on SAS. I do not understand because both use the same test (log-rank).

Does anyone have an explanation ?

Here are the two functions I use in R and SAS to plot survival functions :

```
R : fit <- survfit(Surv(TIME_OS, STATUS_OS)~GROUP, data)
    ggsurvplot(fit, data = data, pval=TRUE)
--> log-rank pval = 0.074

SAS : proc lifetest data=data plots=s(test);
        time time_os*status_os(0);
        strata group;
      run;
--> log-rank pval = 0.054
```

in this example, it's not much different, but sometimes I have two very different values

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Log-rank is not sufficiently specific. There are many possible weighting schemes. Furthermore, you should be looking at the documentation for “survfit” since that’s the function that’s doing the actual work.

Comment: @IRTFM Thank you ! I don't know what the ggsurvplot does but I did differently : I calculated the pvalue with surv_pvalue and then I called it in the option "pval" from the ggsurvplot

Comment: You don’t seem to be reading for meaning. If you used `surv_pvalue`, then you should have looked at the documentation for that function and taken note of its options for the type of log rank test. You should then read the documentation for the SAS proc and compared them.

Comment: From what you've provided these results should match, both pieces of code (assuming default parameters) perform the exact same test. Does your data conform to the expected conventions in both cases, e.g. does your censoring variable take only the values 0/1? Can you provide any data where you do get a difference?